# mach_inject kick start

Tags: macos, code-injection, finder, mach

Current I am trying to inject a bundle to Finder, it all works well and in Activity Monitor I can see my bundle reside in there.

However the code inside my bundle does not execute.

I would like to ask how do I kick start the execution of my code in the bundle?

Currently in the bundle I only have a `void load()` function and inside it print a line to indicate it has loaded to console.

Is it the right way to kick start?

Comment: by the way I am using mach_inject

Answer (score 0):

yes its right. Open `activity monitor --> Finder --> inspect`.  you can see your bundle in `open files and ports`
`Printf` is not working in that function. You can create an temp file and write some data to that file in that function.

```
__attribute__((constructor));
```

The constructor attribute causes the function to be called automatically before execution enters main ().